# Interfacing Saitek Megamaster MX-530 with Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-2, hardware, joystick

I found out an old Saitek Megamaster MX-530 joystick that I used to play games on old Pentium machine with Win XP. I've tried to used on modern system buying midi/game port converter (25 pin) to USB but without any success (I've tried 2 converters).

[image: Saitek Megamaster MK-350 joystick]

So why not trying to use it as Retropie/recalbox console on Raspberry Pi?

I thought that, as the joystick chassis is very big, I could put Raspberry Pi inside it and cut it to export power and HDMI ports.

I think that connecting buttons to Raspberry would be easy, they're digital so I can connect them directly on GPIO but what about the joystick? Is it analog or digital?

Moreover, if it is analog, I must add an Arduino or ATtiny85 to use ADC, someone have done this before and could address me to the right way?

Comment: IMHO, rather than butchering the device, and thereby losing any potential future value as a "retro device", I would make an external interface (in a separate box) that takes the 9 pin Atari plug (or 25 pin or whatever it has) in a socket and which then outputs HDMI or whatever.

Comment: @Greenonline: ok, good suggestion! can you please answer me about the main question: this kind of joystick is analog or digital?

Comment: To begin with it is a [**MX-530**](https://collection.onceuponabyte.org/ident/JOY-0092) *not* a MK-350. Specifying it correctly in your question might garner more accurate answers. Secondly, that site (which uses the *exact same photo* as you have) seems to define it as digital although how accurate that site is, is not clear.